# R - adding Integers of list as column names

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list:

```
my_list <- list(list(1, 1.1, 1.2), list(2, 2.1, 2.2), list(3, 3.1, 3.2))
```

and an empty data.frame:

```
my_df <- data.frame()
```

I want to add the first variable of every "sub"list of my_list to my_df as column names.
My idea:

```
for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    my_df[ , c(my_list[[i]][[1]])] <- NA
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Replacement has 1 row, data have 0
```

Comment: You cannot add an implied column-with-1-row to a 0-row frame.

Comment: data.frame columns have types ? your requirements seem to skip over that ? maybe its best to make a simplified list or simple a vector of names, as a first step and work your way up to a data.frame when/if you understand the needed types  / what the content should be

Comment: You can start by creating a 1-row 0-column frame (as odd as that sounds) using `my_df <- data.frame(1)[,-1]`, after which you can grow your frame correctly. Your code doesn't name the columns, but you can easily add some code for that (or use Friede's answer).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add the first variable of every "sub"list of my_list to my_df as column names.

As long as `my_df` is empty, that is difficult to achieve.
You could try to grow `my_df`'s column dimension to the length of `my_list` like so:

```r
my_list = list(list(1, 1.1, 1.2), list(2, 2.1, 2.2), list(3, 3.1, 3.2))
my_df = data.frame()

fst = lapply(my_list, "[[", 1)
my_df = rbind(my_df, rep(NA, length(fst)))
colnames(my_df) = fst |> unlist() |> as.character()
```

gives

```r
> my_df
   1  2  3
1 NA NA NA
```